# How to change a multindexed dataframe under conditions on index and columns?

Tags: python, pandas

With the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0, 0, 1, 1],
                   'b':[0, 1, 0, 1],
                   'A':['w', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
                   'B':[True, False, True, False],
                   'C':[np.nan]*4}).set_index(['a', 'b'])
```

I want to change the value of `C` where `'a' == 0`, `'A' == w` and `'B' is True`.

I found this solution:

```
temp = df.loc[0]
temp.loc[(temp['A'] == 'w')&(temp['B']), 'C'] = 42
```

The affectation is done but I get the following warning:

```
/home/me/.virtualenvs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:477: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self.obj[item] = s
```

This gives the same warning and doesn't do the affectation:

```
df.query("A == 'w' & B").loc[0, 'C'] = 42
```

Is there a way to do the change in `df` without a warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work without giving a warning.

```
df.loc[(df.index.get_level_values(0) == 0)&(df['A'] == 'w')&(df['B']), 'C'] = 42
```

Comment: This doesn't change the value in df.

Comment: I see, I misunderstood.  In that case, there is no reason to make the temp dataframe.  The following should not give a warning. Does it not do what you are expecting?  `df.loc[(df['A'] == 'w')&(df['B']), 'C'] = 42`

Comment: You forgot the `'a' == 0` condition.

Comment: Haha, sorry it took me so long. This should be it. `df.loc[(df.index.get_level_values(0) == 0)&(df['A'] == 'w')&(df['B']), 'C'] = 42`